# How to Generate PDF in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I want to generate a module which will generate PDF by taking input as my  Invoice  and that PDF file is send to clients  mail id automatic.   In 1st step i got some code and try to generate PDF. That code is working fin and i am able to generate the PDF. but i am not able to open the file.

for code i use this link:http://github.com/marak/pdf.js/

Comment: This link i Use "http://github.com/marak/pdf.js/" and i get some solution to generate PDF... but i face one problem that PDF is not able to open. It is saying some error while Opening...Plz anybody check it out and suggest something..............

Comment: The mentioned github project is "Deprecated - Do not use"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install http://phantomjs.org/ and the install the phantom node module https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

Here is an example of rendering a pdf

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.open("http://www.google.com").then(function(status) {
            page.render('google.pdf').then(function() {
                console.log('Page Rendered');
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I try above code but i m not able to reach in sol. PLz  any idea share here............

Comment: I want to generate PDF through Node.JS and Send that PDF file via mail..PLZ suggest some and which can give something which can workout and give  better solution....

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) (Headless Google Chrome Node API) to generate PDFs:

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the [DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). Puppeteer runs [headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.

You can easily generate a PDF using [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions):

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://example.com/');

  await page.pdf({
    path: 'example.pdf',
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Then you can execute the program straight from Node.js:

```
node puppeteer.js
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to generate a PDF from a template.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, starting from scratch using PDFKit...

Generating PDF's with Express  [https://blog.koenvangilst.nl/generating-a-pdf-with-express/](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)

PDFKit, home page  [https://pdfkit.org/](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)

pdfkit, npm page  https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit