# How to perform pdf report generation in loopback4

Tags: strongloop, loopback4

Is PDF report generation is possible in Loppback4?? Is there any code for the PDF report generation in Loopback4??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Generate PDF in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105873/how-to-generate-pdf-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

LB4 doesn't have a built-in pdf generator. However, you can use any js/ts library to resolve that like using jsPDF, puppeteer, etc.